# 403 forbidden error when displaying svg image

Tags: svg, http-status-code-403

I'm on a Hostgator server, trying to display a svg image, but the image doesn't display, I only get a 'broken image' icon.

When I'm accessing the svg-file directly, it shows a `403 - forbidden` error.

Does this only occur on Hostgator servers? I didn't have have a any problems displaying it on my local machine, before upload.

I have searched Google and Stack Overflow, but had no luck in finding a fix for this.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the file permission is correct and their aren't any firewall role that blocks the SVG files.
you can try another svg file.
also you can try to upload a test file with SVG extension to see that is the problem.