# How do I fix 403 Errors when trying to display an SVG <image>?

Tags: html, css, svg, file-permissions, http-status-code-403

I'm building an interactive report based on this: https://avocode.com/design-report-2017

Everything worked great on localhost, but when I uploaded it to the server, I'm getting a 403 (Forbidden) error for all of the SVG images.

I have tried using both relative and absolute paths for the images. Images not in `<image>` tags (regular `<img>`) work well.

Based on this question: [403 forbidden error when displaying svg image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157431/403-forbidden-error-when-displaying-svg-image), it really sounds like the problem is that the server does not have the proper permissions to load SVG images.

However, I can't seem to find what the permissions need to be *changed to*. I don't have access to make server changes and have no idea what to tell the back-end developer to change.

I've also read that xlink:href is deprecated (https://css-tricks.com/on-xlinkhref-being-deprecated-in-svg/) and should be replaced with `<use>`, but I can't find documentation on how to use `<use>` tags in conjunction with `<image>` tags. MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) and W3C (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#ImageElement) still use xlink:href in their `<image>` documentation.

If the error is due to xlink:href deprecation, how do I properly reference an image file within an `<svg>`? If `<use>` is the preferred method, how would I rewrite the above code to accommodate?

Any help on rewriting my code to properly display the images or reconfiguring the server to display them would be a life-saver.

Thank you for your time.

My code is below:

```
<div title aria-label="aimation" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" viewbox="0 -100 800 1000" width="1340" height="1440" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <g>
      <g id="o-phone" class="image" transform="translate(-500 500)">
        <image width="500px" height="300px" href="/img/omnichannel/Phone.svg"></image>
      </g>

      <g id="o-floating-shelf" class="image" transform="translate(750 -200)">
        <image width="120px" height="300px" href="/img/omnichannel/Floating Shelves.svg"></image>
      </g>

      <g id="o-bookshelf1" class="image" transform="translate(445 -1000)">
        <image width="150px" height="300px" href="/img/omnichannel/Bookshelf.svg"></image>
      </g>

      <g id="o-stack1" class="image" transform="translate(520 -500)">
        <image width="35px" height="300px" href="/img/omnichannel/Stack Back Bottom.svg"></image>
      </g>

      <g id="o-bookshelf2" class="image" transform="translate(420 -1000)">
        <image width="150px" height="300px" href="/img/omnichannel/Bookshelf.svg"></image>
      </g>

      <g id="o-stack2" class="image" transform="translate(390 -500)">
        <image width="35px" height="300px" href="/img/omnichannel/Stack Front Bottom.svg"></image>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: What webserver are you using? Could you perhaps post some of its logs? This really sounds like a server side issue to me.

Comment: @Benni Unfortunately, I'm just the front-end dev and have no access to anything related to the server. It is an Apache server with WordPress on top, if that helps.

Comment: I'm almost certain it's a server side issue. Could you perhaps attach a screenshot of the permissions on your svg file?

Comment: @Benni Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/lSeH7I6.

Comment: Sorry for not asking for this before, but what are the permissions on other files you can open using your browser (e.g. an HTML file)?

Comment: @Benni -rw-r--r--

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but is the owner of the SVG files (`staff`) the same as the owner of the HTML files? Also, did you try opening the files in your browser?

Comment: @Benni If I open the file directly, I get a 403. See here: https://imgur.com/a/s8jO5qz. Staff (I believe) is just because it's a work machine.

Comment: Can you have a look, what user owns the HTML files, that are working correctly? I'm suspecting an issue there.

Comment: I wouldn't use this sort of file names: `Stack Front Bottom.svg`, `Floating Shelves.svg` Can you try to rename those files to something like `Stack_Front_Bottom.svg`, `Floating_Shelves.svg` and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little more research and the help of @Benni, problem solved!

Turns out the issue was with file permissions. To solve:

1. In Terminal, navigate to the folder and enter `ls -l` so see the current list of file permissions. Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/528411/how-do-you-view-file-permissions
2. Got something that looked like `-rwxr-xr-x`. A great explanation of what these letters mean can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types
3. In order to change permissions, enter `chmod -R 775 [folder]`. Including `-R` changes the permissions of all the files and folders in the subdirectories as well. A few tutorials said the set the permissions to 755, but that didn't solve the problem. Went with 775, which did the trick.
4. In addition, I found that you can configure various FTP clients to handle permissions for you. See instructions here: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ftp/change-permissions/

If anyone else runs into this issue, I hope this answer will be helpful/valuable.